# Magento2: Get Quote details in view page

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I can't get the current quote in the Product view page. I have 3 items in my cart.

I have used both files.

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

$quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
echo $quote->getId();
```

But, I can't get it. After that adding new product in view page. I can got it.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you use this code ? In observer or? Please explain more.

Comment: I used this code in the custom model file in view page.

Comment: I want to get a quote on page load

Comment: Let me know if you still can't able to get quote.

Answer (score 1):

I think u have to add getAllVisibleItems() for get quote item

```
<?php
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cartData = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    echo $cartData->getId();
?>
```

Comment: Its also not working